# How can I get the addresses of the owners of a perticular Nft using metaplex

Tags: transactions, nft, metaplex-js, solana-pay

What type of nft ( master, printed , normal edition ) should I need to share with user so that, later I can get the details who are the owners of that perticular Nft or whether user address contains that nft or not .

[image: just like atlas cafe did with transaction request]

just like atlas cafe did with transaction request.

Answer (score 0):

When a Solana Pay QR code is scanned by a wallet, the wallet sends a post request to the transaction request URL with its public key.

When building the transaction to return the wallet, you can use the metaplex SDK to fetch all NFTs owned by the provided public key.

Here's the metaplex SDK: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#findAllByOwner

One possible solution would be to mint users NFTs that are part of the same collection, and then check if a wallet holds an NFT of that collection.

Check out the metaplex docs for how collections work: https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/certified-collections

Here's a great tutorial on that walks through how to build Solana Pay transaction requests: https://www.pointer.gg/tutorials/solana-pay-irl-payments/944eba7e-82c6-4527-b55c-5411cdf63b23